# Last USA exit or USA last exit

Tags: adjectives, word-order

Can you please confirm which of these sentence is correct. Thank you!

"This is Last USA exit"
or
"This is USA last exit"

Sentence should give meaning as below:
- This is a final exit of USA(probably if you miss it, you will be in another country).

Comment: https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3216/3871302826_d608a86284_b.jpg

Comment: @Slepz - I did not ask for where it is mentioned, I am trying to understand which one is correct and why.

If I really need a pic, I could have got somewhere on internet :). So please do not unnecessarily waste your comment. Thanks!

Comment: @Srekk I rather think that picture is giving you the answer. However, if you want to know **why** "Last" needs to come before "US" then you need to add that to your question. So far you have only asked which option is correct.

Comment: Neither of those are complete sentences, and without context it is impossible to say if one is 'correct'.

Comment: @Andrew - I think I have added meaning to the question I have asked. The one that gives exact meaning should be correct sentence in my opinion. Not sure why it is down rated. That's ok. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I agree with @DJClayworth. As soon as I saw the title of the question I thought of "signspeak". That would make it a different story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"last USA exit" is correct. That's saying that this particular exit is the last one that leads to territory in the USA, as the next exit will lead to Canada.

To say, "USA Last Exit" is to say if you want to access the USA, wait until the last exit, as the ones before that will not be in the USA.

Comment: Good one! Looks like I have to read your post couple of times to understand better. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Reading the last sentence sort of makes me laugh. I can imagine such a sign being on a freeway - USA LAST EXIT - and interpreting it as "the US was the exit you just passed, hahaha *troll face*"

Comment: The signs of this sort that I have seen in the US are along these lines: Last Exit in X, where X could be USA, NY, or any other state name.